# Hibernate functions lower and upper not working on Polish special characters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpql

I have a problem with a lower and upper function in JPA (Hibernate). In my application a user should add a new item to the database, but the name should be unique. In order to achieve that, I need to compare user entered string with the strings in the database and ignore case while checking that.

Unfortunately, as I am using the Hibernate function to make all data upper-cased (in order to compare that) everything works fine except for the Polish special characters that remain the same.

This is the code I've used for testing purposes in order to check if it works:

```
TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery("SELECT upper(i.name) FROM Item i", String.class);

for (String name: query.getResultList())
    System.out.println(name);
```

And that's what I get:

- CZYSTY BANDAż
- MAłY CHEMIK
- MAłY MECHANIK
- SPRZęT
- ŚPIWóR
- ŚRODEK DEZYNFEKUJąCY
- ŚRODEK CZYSZCZąCY

All letters should be upper-cased. In the database every first letter of a first word is always capitalized. The problem concerns such characters like: **ą, ę, ż, ź, ó, ł** - they should look like **Ą, Ę, Ż, Ź, Ó, Ł**, but Hibernate seems not to recognize them as a single character which differs only in regard to the case.

The same thing happens when I use a lower function. Polish characters are not affected at all and remain the same.

I do not know if it concerns only Polish characters or from any other languages too.

I would be very grateful for any hint in this matter.

EDIT: I'm using Hibernate 5.2.2 Final with SQLite database and driver Xerial 3.8.11.2.

EDIT2: The same happens if I try to achieve that using native SQL query with Hibernate.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @khalilM I'm using Hibernate 5.2.2 Final and Xerial 3.8.11.2 with SQLite database :)

Comment: but "ł" works fine?

Comment: @khaliM sorry I've forgotten to include that, "ł" should be changed to "Ł" too

Comment: just check your database/hibernate or Jsp UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @khalilM I've checked database already and it is UTF-8, in persistence.xml I have these properties: `<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"></property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"></property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"></property>`, so I think Hibernate should use UTF-8 too. I don't have any other issues with these signs in entire application except for that.

Comment: When you looked at the SQL generated by your JPA provider what did you see? You have looked at the SQL ?

Comment: I had a problem with log4j2 configuarion and I couldn't make it show me parameters that were passed while executing queries, but as I wrote in my answer below, it doesn't matter while it was SQLite's fault :) The same happens if I execute these functions in the database only. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the solution. It turned out, that SQLite doesn't support the Unicode collation. It can only support ASCII latin characters while using lower, upper function or sorting.

There is an extension (SQLite ICU Extension), that SQLite must be compiled with in order to use Unicode collation (or other collations), but as far as I'm concerned it is not as simple solution as I would like it to be. I've decided to change the database provider to H2, which support Unicode collation by default without performing any modifications and it works like a charm now :)

So it's not Hibernate's fault, but the SQLite's. Thank you very much for your help :)